# Play - Querying many to many relationships

Tags: java, sql, playframework-2.0, many-to-many, ebean

I'm using play framework with ebean.
I have 2 classes that share a many-to-many relationship

```
@Entity
public class profiles extends Model {

@Id
@Column(name = "profile_ID")
public Integer _id;

public String profile;
public String description;

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
public List<role> roles;
......

@Entity
public class role extends Model {
@Id
@Column(name = "role_ID")
public Integer _id;

public String role;
public Integer parent;
public String description;
public Integer sequence;

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
public ArrayList<profiles> prof_ids = new ArrayList<profiles>();
    .....
```

I'm having trouble trying to generate a list containing all the roles that a particular profile has. 
could anyone show me how this is done?

Comment: Is there a query that you have tried? If so, please add it to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide more information on what specifically you're trying to do.

See below for an action that creates a profile with 2 roles, persists the profile (and roles), finds all profiles, logs the found profiles and their associated roles and then renders them as JSON:

```
public class Profiles extends Controller {

    public static Result create() {
        profiles profile = new profiles();
        profile.description = "Testing";
        profile.profile = "Test Profile";

        role role = new models.role();
        role.description = "Test Role 1";
        role.role = "Role 1";
        profile.roles.add(role);

        role = new models.role();
        role.description = "Test Role 2";
        role.role = "Role 2";
        profile.roles.add(role);

        profile.save();

        List<profiles> profiles = Ebean.find(profiles.class).findList();
        for (profiles p : profiles) {
            Logger.info("Profile: {}", p.profile);
            for (role r : p.roles) {
                Logger.info("\t-> has role: {}", r.role);
            }
        }

        return ok(Json.toJson(profiles)).as("application/json");
    }
}
```

To get the list of roles, note the reference to `p.roles` above. Is that what you want?

[See here](http://www.avaje.org/ebean/introquery.html) for more advanced queries etc.

Some things to keep in mind:

- Always start your class names with a capital letter in Java. The code above is hard to read using your lowercase model/entity names...
- Name your entity identifier `id` not `_id`, it causes issues when Ebean generates queries.

Comment: Thanks for the help, this pretty much solves the problem I was having.

Comment: @user2801159 No problem, glad to help. If you feel I've answered your question, would you mind accepting my answer?